# SQL IN Operator for Concatenated values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

| ID | News_Code | News_Digits |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | GBX | 400 |
| 2 | NXC | 670 |
| 3 | LBO | 880 |

I have several codes, what I need to check that code are in `News_Code` & `news_Digit` section. My code is like this:

```
'LBX 345','NXC 670'
```

What I have tried:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblNews 
WHERE News_Code IN ('LBX 345', 'NXC 670')` // But here is the problem is not only the news_code we need to consider the News_Digit as well.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can concatenate the two columns and then compare:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblNews 
WHERE News_Code + ' ' + News_Digits IN ('LBX 345', 'NXC 670')
```

If `News_Digits` is not a string data type, you can change that by casting it:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblNews 
WHERE News_Code + ' ' + CAST(News_Digits AS VARCHAR(3)) IN ('LBX 345', 'NXC 670')
```

Comment: This will not be able to use any index on the table, though, which may or may not matter depending on the size

Answer (score 1):

You can join a `VALUES` virtual table (or use a real table variable, Table Valued Parameter or temp table)

```sql
SELECT n.*
FROM tblNews n
JOIN (VALUES
  ('LBX', 345),
  ('NXC', 670)
) v(News_Code, News_Digits)
  ON v.News_Code = n.News_Code
 AND v.News_Digits = n.News_Digits;
```